# How to find coords from angle in a circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, limit, coords

I'm trying to find the coords of the red point in the image, I have the mouse coords, the initial point and the radio but I don't know how to find the coords of the red point.

[image]

I am using JavaScript and canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- First find the angle between the mouse point and center of circle
- Then calculate the needed point using that angle and radius of circle

To find the angle:

```
var diffX = mouseX - centerX;
var diffY = mouseY - centerY;
var angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);
```

To find the new point use that angle with radius:

```
var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle);
var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/8MYyg/)**

Comment: LOL just post something similar. I thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

first find the angle between the mouse and the point.

```
dx = mouseCoordX - coordX;
dy = mouseCoordY - coordY;
angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

second, find the coords of the red point

```
coordToFindX = coordX+ Math.cos(angle ) * radio
coordToFindY = coordY + Math.sin(angle ) * radio
```